# How to correctly add the onHoverIn TS type for the React Native Web Pressable component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-native-web

I'm using React Native Web in combination with Typescript and I would like to use the [React Native Web Pressable](https://necolas.github.io/react-native-web/docs/pressable/) component from the lib.

However, I faced a problem when the VSCode blames the React Native Web prop types like **onHoverIn**. The main issue in this situation is that the React Native prop types definition doesn't contain the *enhanced* props from RNWeb

Could someone, please, give to me a tip on how it could be solved in the right way?
I wouldn't like to disable TS checking in every file where I'd like to use Pressable

Here is the Error message:

```
type '{ 
children: Element; 
accessibilityRole: "button"; 
delayLongPress: number; 
disabled: false; 
onHoverIn: () => void; 
onHoverOut: () => void; 
onKeyDown: () => void; 
onLongPress: () => void; 
onPress: () => void; 
onPressIn: () => void; 
onPressOut: () => void; }' is not assignable to type 
  'IntrinsicAttributes & PressableProps & RefAttributes<View>'.

Property 'onHoverIn' does not exist on type
  'IntrinsicAttributes & PressableProps & RefAttributes<View>'.ts(2322)
```

The code example:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Text, Button, ScrollView, StyleSheet, View, Pressable 
} from 'react-native'; // in webpack conf I have an alias that fetches data from the React Native Web

....

 <Pressable
    accessibilityRole="button"
    delayLongPress={750}
    disabled={false}
    onHoverIn={() => {
      console.log('onHoverIn');
    }}
    onHoverOut={() => {
      console.log('onHoverOut');
    }}
  >
    <Text>Pressable</Text>
  </Pressable>
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve this problem in only one "not-bad" way. It's just creating the Component wrapper that re-exports the original Pressable but contains the enhanced props.

I'm not sure this is the "best one" solution because we must physically create some React Component as a wrapper but our problem is relative to types only

The working example:

```
// This file is mainly for extending the basic Pressable RN props type
// by the React Native Web-specific properties to avoid TS blaming
import * as React from 'react';
import {
  Pressable as RNWebPressable,
  PressableProps as RNWebPressableProps
} from 'react-native';

export type PressableProps = RNWebPressableProps & {
  // RNWeb properties
  onHoverIn: (e: MouseEvent) => void;
  onHoverOut: (e: MouseEvent) => void;
}

export function Pressable(props: PressableProps) {
  return (
    <RNWebPressable {...props} />
  );
}
```